# QGIS clipping DEM returns NaN

Tags: qgis, raster, geojson, dem

I was previously clipping a DEM (SRTM 30m) with one GeoJSON polygon and getting good results. With another GeoJSON polygon, I'm getting NaN values for the clipped raster. Any ideas on what is going on?

The good polygon:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "_slopemean": 89.991593497140073,
            "_slopestdev": 0.0007812262490126589,
            "_slopemin": 89.990058898925781,
            "_slopemax": 89.9927978515625,
            "_aspectmean2": null,
            "_aspectstdev2": null,
            "_aspectmin2": null,
            "_aspectmax2": null
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[35.465406775474548,
            33.033829221177918],
            [35.463507771492004,
            33.032489029387897],
            [35.464510917663567,
            33.032668922087709],
            [35.465508699417114,
            33.032875798238493],
            [35.465970039367676,
            33.033100663068907],
            [35.465980768203735,
            33.033316532766257],
            [35.465701818466187,
            33.033392986490597],
            [35.465406775474548,
            33.033829221177918]]]
        }
    }]
}
```

The bad polygon:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32718"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "Name",
            "description": null,
            "timestamp": null,
            "begin": null,
            "end": null,
            "altitudeMode": null,
            "tessellate": -1,
            "extrude": 0,
            "visibility": -1,
            "drawOrder": null,
            "icon": null,
            "stroke": "#555555",
            "stroke_width": "2",
            "stroke_opacity": "1",
            "fill": "#555555",
            "fill_opacity": "0.5",
            "Code": "Name"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[[35.543979406356812,
            33.17158011534832,
            0.0],
            [35.543362498283393,
            33.169757071127393,
            0.0],
            [35.543459057807922,
            33.16957296849484,
            0.0],
            [35.544124245643623,
            33.171535213236737,
            0.0],
            [35.543979406356812,
            33.17158011534832,
            0.0]]]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Its look like you somehow change the defined CRS on the "*bad*" polygon. There is UTM (`EPSG::32718`) while geometry is in WGS84 (`EPSG::4326`)

Comment: Is there a good way to fix this from within QGIS?

Comment: You can change layer CRS in `Layer prorerties` in `General` tab.

Comment: I've done this for the offending polygon, to no avail.

Comment: Sorry to butt in here, but I feel you need to save the polygon as a new GeoJSON file and reload it to the project. Right-click the layer in the layer panel, select `Save As`, and then change the CRS to WGS84.

Comment: When you view the "bad" polygon and the DEM in the map display, do they overlap?

Comment: They do overlap, which is why I am confused at my inability to clip one to the other.